# What changed the Judge's sympathy?

Tags: plot-explanation, find-me-guilty

In [Find Me Guilty](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0419749/), at the beginning of the trial, Judge Finestein had little empathy for Jackie DiNorscio. This can be shown by the Judge slapping first a $5000 then upping it to $10000 fine for Contempt of Court. He also is more apt to sustain the Prosecutor's objections.

By the end of the trial, the Judge appears very sympathetic to Jackie D., for example, the way he expresses complete understanding and remorse for Jackie when DiNorscio's mother passes. IIRC, he overrules objections by the Prosecutor and sustains the Defenses, esp Jackie D's.

I never get the feeling that the 'mob' bought the Judge, but rather he has become more sympathetic towards them, again especially concerning Jackie.

Can anyone site specific (objective) examples of what precipitates this change of heart?

Comment: Vin Diesel with hair ... who'd a thunk it? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I state few reasons why Judge might have felt sympathy for Jackie DiNorscio

1 - Jackie gets beaten up so badly in the prison by some guys and the next day when the Judge ask him what happened, he says he fell.

2 - Tony shoots him thrice even though Jackie's saying "coz, what are you doing? I love you."

3 - Jackie pays for Tony's mother's funeral.(normally what good guys do.)

4 - Jackie shows a old picture of his gang to the citizens in the court and says about how they're conspiring to buy an ice cream in front of the parlour.

5 - In the end, citizens in the court gives verdict and says that they find all the defendants are not guilty despite all the evidence and witnesses.

Jackie is very clever and he knows the only way he is gonna win is by gaining public's and judge's sympathy that's why he keeps mentioning about gang members' families and their children and repeatedly asks the public not to separate the gang members from their family by sending them jail and in the end he tells to his gang to bring fake families to the court on final verdict to gain more sympathy.

The scenes I've explained above may not be exact 'cause I've seen this long ago but I thoroughly enjoyed the movie.